# Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in. Error al realizar consulta de Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql

Llevo un par de horas intentando realizar una consulta de una base de datos de Mysql a través de un formulario de Php. El problema es que me apareció el siguiente error:

Después de mucho buscar, no encuentro una solución certera que me ayude a resolver esto.
Anexo el código.

````
    introducir el código aquí

$servidor = "localhost:3308";
$nombreusuario = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "agendaphp";
$tabla = "datos";

$conexion = new mysqli ($servidor, $nombreusuario, $password, $db);

if($conexion->connect_error){
    die("conexion fallida". $conexion->connect_error);
} 

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];

$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM  datos WHERE Nombre = $nombre") or die( mysqli_error($db));

**while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){**

    introducir el código aquí
    ```

en el renglón dearriba es en donde marca el error.



Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.
De antemano muchísimas gracias.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta está mal, debes agregar entre comillas el elemento de tu consulta

```
"SELECT * FROM  datos WHERE Nombre = $nombre"
```

Debería quedar como

```
"SELECT * FROM  datos WHERE Nombre = '$nombre'"
```

O usar `mysqli_prepare`

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, "SELECT * FROM  datos WHERE Nombre = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $nombre);
$resultados = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!
Resolviste mi problema.
Le envié mis archivos a mi maestro de programación y en lugar de arreglarlo me los regresó con problemas y modificó mi código.
Me acabas de ayudar un montón,
Dios te bendiga hermano.
Espero que consigas una leñadora en bikini, te la mereces.